# How to use "com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.export.pdf.modern.ModernPdfProducerFactory" programmatically

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, itext7

When using with Jasperreport Library programmatically, how can we change the default PDF producer to the iText7 producer?

i.e. com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.export.pdf.modern.ModernPdfProducerFactory

---

already tried to set the following before invoking export but FAILED:

`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.PDF_PRODUCER_FACTORY_PROPERTY = "com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.export.pdf.modern.ModernPdfProducerFactory";`

Answer (score 0):

Got answered from github of jasperreports-pdf-lib7, quoted below:

---

You can set the PDF producer property programmatically like this:

`DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance().setProperty(JRPdfExporter.PDF_PRODUCER_FACTORY_PROPERTY,      "com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.export.pdf.modern.ModernPdfProducerFactory");`

You can also use ModernPdfProducerFactory.class.getName() as property value if you don't mind a compile dependency.